# Класс для обработки событий

Tags: php, ооп

Добрый день! Пытаюсь написать свой первый php класс, задача вроде бы не сложная, но что-то второй день не могу понять принцип.

Есть некое подобие класса, набросок:

```
class Callback
{
    public $token;
    public $confirm;

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->token = $config['token'];
        $this->confirm = $config['confirm'];
    }

    public function event($type)
    {
        //
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    }
}
```

Пример его использования:

```
$config = [
    'token' => 'token',
    'confirm' => 'confirm',
];

$callback = new Callback($config);

$callback->event('one');
$callback->event('two');
$callback->event('three');

$callback->run();
```

Когда происходит событие - на сервер приходит post запрос, содержащий json:

```
{"type": <тип события>, "object": <объект, инициировавший событие>, "group_id": <ID сообщества, в котором произошло событие>}
```

Не могу понять принцип, по которому можно проверить событие записанное в `run()`, c событиями которые находятся в `event()` и если такое событие есть - сделать что-то, а если такого события нет - сделать что-нибудь другое. Можете помочь полезными советами?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно, каким образом связаны event  и run. Но, надеюсь, вы понимаете, что экземпляр вашего класса будет жить только во время исполнения скрипта и, если вы надеетесь собрать несколько POST-запросов и для всех них использовать один метод run, то вам не обойтись без отчуждаемого хранилища (БД например)

Comment: @rjhdby я как раз про связь и спрашиваю. Не пойму принцип связывание. в event() указываются события которые нужно обработать, в run() приходит событие и если в event() есть совпадение с run() - обработать событие.

Comment: По вашему примеру, метод run не принимает никаких аргументов, если принимает - правил свое сообщение.

Comment: @KonstantinSoroka в переменной $data есть POST-запрос который приходит от VK:  http://ssmaker.ru/73a8a722.png

Comment: Ответ поправил под эти данные

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем примере без указания того что делает метод `event` и не видя связи с методом `run` сложно конкретное что-то подсказать.
Как вариант в методе `event` заносите в закрытую переменную, нужные вам данные о событии.

```
private $container = array();
//
public function event($type)
{
    $this->container[] = $type;
    //
}

public function run()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if (in_array($data['type'], $this->container)) {
     // действия если событие поступало в метод event
    } else {
     // действия если событие НЕ поступало в метод event
    }    
}
```

Эта переменная будет доступна для метода `run` но будет не доступна из вне. Опираясь на подобную реализацию можете реализовать нужную Вам связь.

Comment: Я как раз про связь и спрашиваю. Не пойму принцип связывание. Кручу второй день методом "тыка", но без успешно.

Comment: Исходя из Вашего ответа другому участнику, в методе event добавляйте тип в массив который доступен внутри этого класса а в методе run проверяйте if (in_array($typeToRun, $this->container) и выполняйте что Вам нужно.

Comment: @KonstantinSoroka Возможно Родион не понимает код, который вы написали. Опишите словами внутри ответа что происходит в коде.